# value getting changed during SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, csv, sqlbulkcopy

I am trying to upload some data from csv file to sql server using SqlBulkCopy
The problem here is that the values get changed automatically
eg 0.9824 becomes 0.982400000095367

Here is the code that I am using

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("dt", typeof(DateTime)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("wreb", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("zid", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("zone_name", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("region", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("iloss", typeof(float)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("dloss", typeof(float)));

            for (int i = 0; i < DataDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow myDr = dt.NewRow();
                myDr["dt"] = DateTime.ParseExact(DataDS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["dt"].ToString(), "d/M/yyyy", null);
                myDr["wreb"] = DataDS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["wreb"].ToString();
                myDr["zid"] = DataDS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["zid"].ToString();
                myDr["zone_name"] = DataDS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["zone_name"].ToString();
                myDr["region"] = DataDS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["region"].ToString();
                myDr["iloss"] = DataDS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["iloss"].ToString();
                myDr["dloss"] = DataDS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["dloss"].ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(myDr);
                myDr = null;
            }
            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("dt", "Zdate");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("wreb", "Entity");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("zid", "ZoneID");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("zone_name", "Zone_Name");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("region", "region");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("iloss", "iloss");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("dloss", "dloss");
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tbl_zloss";
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're using [float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) which is an imprecise datatype.
Use [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) to get exact values. Precision and scale depend on your data